# Expression Web 4 SP2 bug

Tags: expression-web, microsoft-expression-web

I have this annoying bug in **MS Expression Web 4 SP2**, weird GUI quirks: you can see in the picture: like parts of the display isn't being painted. I had this before, and solved it by uninstalling something, but the problem is that I don't remember what it was... (I installed Exp.Web in fresh Win7 PC, and step by step installing everything, until this problem came up.)

Anybody came across this issue maybe ?

[image: MS Expression Web 4 SP2 bug]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a program called [FileBox eXtender](http://www.hyperionics.com/files/index.asp). It's excellent program I use to pin windows to have them always on top (never be hidden by other windows), because it does its job and it's free. Unfortunately, MS-Expression (Web, Blend, etc...) doesn't get along with it, so I excluded it (somewhere in FileBox-eXtender's options) and now it's o.k.